# Add user-defined color box in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How would I go about creating a small box with a color previously defined by the user, in a UITableView?  Something similar to what the "Things" app has.  (http://culturedcode.com/styles_2.5/images-things-iphone/tt-screenshot-sortedbyduedate.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a custom table cell View. You can create one of these views programmatically
or you may design one in interface builder. You will need a view controller for this custom cell view and then when you providing the table view with table cell views through its delegate function you just instantiate a new custom view and return that.

Edit:

Heres a link to a tutorial...
[Custom Table Cell View Tutorial](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284)